# Failed to connect to a windows service

Tags: windows-7, windows, services

Windows could not connect to the System Event Notification Service service. This problem prevents standard users from logging on to the system. As an administrative user, you can review the System Event Log for details about why the service didn't respond.

Also my aero theme does not work. So everytime i switch on my pc, i go to services then restart the themes service to allow my aero theme to work.

I am using windows 7 32bit, and i recently bought a wireless usb.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I encounter it as well...

Answer (score 0):

See this fix,

http://www.techmalaya.com/2009/01/26/fix-could-not-connect-to-the-system-event-notification-service-error-windows-vista/

Your wireless usb driver may have caused it.

.

Is the Themes service set to "Automatic" for the startup type?

.

Comment: I tried the fix, but still the error message is shown after rebooting, Yes my theme is automatic, but if i restart the service my aero theme works. I also thing the wireless usb driver caused.